# spring mvc mapping - send value between controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3, thymeleaf

I have got webapp in spring 3 mvc. The case is that I have index page with url, when user click on them should be display another page with details of choosed information. Now the details page is shown but without any information (on index page is creating model with correct variable but not in details controller - in debug mode).
index controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{site}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showDetails(@RequestParam(value = "site", required = true) String  site, Model model){
    Catalog product = catalogEndpoint.getByTitle(site);
    model.addAttribute("product", product);
    return "details";
    }
```

index html:

```
<form action="#" th:object="${product}" method="post" th:action="@{/details}">
    <table border="0" width="600"  th:each="sb, poz : ${product}" >
<tr >
<td rowspan="3" width="20"><span th:text="${poz.count}"></span></td> 
<td>
<a  th:href="@{/details/(site=${sb.tytul})}" th:value="${site}"><span  th:text="${sb.tytul}"></span></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
<td><span th:text="${sb.adres}"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>category:<b><span th:text="${sb.category.name}"></span></b></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
    </form>
```

details controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "details/{site}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHomePage(@PathVariable(value = "site") String site, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("product");
    return "details";
}
```

details html:

```
<form th:object="${product}" method="get" th:action="@{/details}">
    <table border="1" width="600"   >
<tr >
<td ><span th:text="${tytul}"></span></td> 
<td>
<span th:text="${opis}"></span>
    </td>
<td><span th:text="${adres}"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I don't have any ideas how to map the details site (I tried a lot of solution but nothing). Thanks for help.

Comment: With thymeleaf, this `@{/details/(site=${sb.tytul})}` evaluates to, ex. `http://yourhost.com/context/details?site=tytul`. Does your controller map to that?

Comment: Yes the controller maps ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thymeleaf, using [`th:object`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax), you need to reference the fields of that object with `*{}`

```
<form th:object="${product}" method="get" th:action="@{/details}">
    <table border="1" width="600"   >
<tr >
<td ><span th:text="*{tytul}"></span></td> 
<td>
<span th:text="*{opis}"></span>
    </td>
<td><span th:text="*{adres}"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

assuming `tytul`, `opis`, and `adres` are fields of `product`. Unless it's a type, don't forget

```
Catalog product = catalogEndpoint.getByTitle(site);
model.addAttribute("product", product);
```

in your `details` controller method, otherwise you won't have a `Catalog` model attribute.

Answer (score 0):

inside your details controller where are you setting product object in your model ?

```
 model.addAttribute("product");
```

is just settingstring object "product", fetch the product object and set it in details controller like you have done in showDetails method

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
model.addAttribute("product");
```

To

```
Catalog product = catalogEndpoint.getByTitle(site);
model.addAttribute("product", product);
```

in "showPage" method.